# Raspberry PI USB Webcam - Logitech Quickcam 9000

Tags: streaming-video, webcam

I have been trying to stream my webcam over http with a raspberry pi 2 using mjpg-streamer. It works to stream the webcam and also some of the image controls, like brightness, focus, etc...

What I cannot seem to get to work is the zoom controls on the logitech's QuickCam Pro 9000. On a windows PC with the logitech software, I am able to zoom in and out. Yet, using mjpg-streamer, I am unable to replicate this control.

I have looked at a lot of links such as: http://www.slblabs.com/2012/09/26/rpi-webcam-stream. (Note: I cannot post more right now as I do not have a high enough rep. See more links in the question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416229/raspberry-pi-usb-webcam-logitech-quickcam-9000))

Yet, I have not been able to figure out the zoom control for the webcam. Anyone have any idea how to get the zoom controls working with mjpg-streamer or another video streamer for USB webcam for the raspberry pi?

Note: I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416229/raspberry-pi-usb-webcam-logitech-quickcam-9000) as well, and they said I may be able to get an answer if I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there are no zoom controls for the webcam. The windows software simply does a digital zoom on the video feed from the webcam.

If you would like this feature for mjpeg-streamer, then it may be an idea to use a javascript script to add some sort digital zoom controls for the video feed from the webcam in the browser.